# How to solve the ODE: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y\big(\frac{dy}{dx}\big)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the non-linear ODE  $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y\big(\frac{dy}{dx}\big)^2$ and I would appreciate some suggestions on how to approach this equation. This is actually part of a more complex PDE which I managed to separate but I am puzzled when it comes to solve the above non-linear problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$$

$$\implies \frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx}=y\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 $$

$$\implies \frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dy}{dx}}=ydy $$

Comment: are you suggesting that I should change the variable $x \rightarrow u=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and then write the equation as $\frac{1}{u}du=ydy$ and then integrate?

Comment: could you please check the solution bellow?

Answer (score 2):

Solution: (using the suggestion of @lab bhattacharjee I worked out the following)

We make the change of variable $x \rightarrow u=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Next we take the derivative wrt $x$ : $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx} \implies \frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d^2y }{dx^2} \implies \frac{du}{dy}u=\frac{d^2y }{dx^2}$.

Now, we can write the equation in the form:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{du}{dy} u=y u^2
\end{equation}
  which is a separable ODE with solution $u=Ce^{\frac{y^2}{2}}$ .

The solution for $u$ can be used in the equation $u=\frac{dy}{dx}$ above to find an implicit solution for the original ODE in the form $C\int e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}} dy+D=x\implies C\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}erf\big(\frac{y}{\sqrt 2}\big)+D=x$.

Comment: why have you used partial derivative instead of total? You are also left with using http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e^%28-x^2%29+dx

Comment: changed the sign for derivative and completed the solution. Thank you.